# Fetching values from email in protractor test case

Tags: javascript, email, testing, protractor, mailcatcher

I need to test a protractor test case in which a user signs up, receives an email, goes to the link provided in the email and fills up his/her details in activation signup form.

The problem is how can I get the redeem token from the email. My email has a link to the activation page which has the auth token like following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/#/signup/redeem/eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJqdGkiOiJlOTRhYzY3MC1kYTNlLTQyYTUtODVkZS02NDU4ZjVmZGMwYjAiLCJzdWIiOiJ0ZXN0QGNvZWYuY28iLCJpYXQiOjE0Mjc0OTM5MDMsImV4cCI6MTQyODA5ODcwM30.
```

But how do I fetch that token so that I can build the url or how can I click that button in my email so that I can complete the flow ? I am using mailcatcher to simulate email.

Comment: disposable webmail systems like Inbucket will also help to solve this scenario. You can fetch email by using it's REST API - https://github.com/jhillyerd/inbucket/wiki/REST-API

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is something I've solved recently. Hope the solution would also apply for your use-case.

Prerequisites:

- [`mail-listener2` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mail-listener2)
- understanding of the concept of `promises`

Step by step instructions:

1. Install `mail-listener2`:

   ```
   npm install mail-listener2 --save-dev
   ```
2. In your protractor config *initialize Mail Listener* and make it available globally:

   ```
   onPrepare: function () {
       var MailListener = require("mail-listener2");

       // here goes your email connection configuration
       var mailListener = new MailListener({
           username: "imap-username",
           password: "imap-password",
           host: "imap-host",
           port: 993, // imap port 
           tls: true,
           tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
           mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor 
           searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved 
           markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time 
           fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`, 
           mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib. 
           attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory 
           attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments 
       });

       mailListener.start();

       mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
           console.log("Mail listener initialized");
       });

       global.mailListener = mailListener;
   }),

   onCleanUp: function () {
       mailListener.stop();
   },
   ```
3. Create a helper `getLastEmail()` function which would wait for an `email` to be retrieved:

   ```
   function getLastEmail() {
       var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
       console.log("Waiting for an email...");

       mailListener.on("mail", function(mail){
           deferred.fulfill(mail);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
   };
   ```
4. Example test case:

   ```
   describe("Sample test case", function () {

       beforeEach(function () {
           browser.get("/#login");
           browser.waitForAngular();
       });

       it("should login with a registration code sent to an email", function () {
           element(by.id("username")).sendKeys("MyUserName");
           element(by.id("password")).sendKeys("MyPassword");
           element(by.id("loginButton")).click();

           browser.controlFlow().await(getLastEmail()).then(function (email) {
               expect(email.subject).toEqual("New Registration Code");
               expect(email.headers.to).toEqual("myemail@email.com");

               // extract registration code from the email message
               var pattern = /Registration code is: (\w+)/g;
               var regCode = pattern.exec(email.text)[1];

               console.log(regCode);

            });
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look at it and will accept your answer.

Comment: @ashish thanks, I've been using the provided approach for a while and it works for me perfectly. Hope you can say the same.

Comment: Hey @alecxe, my requirement is to receive the mails directly while your solution can be used to read from a mail server. We are using mail catcher to fetch the mail but mail-listener2 cannot read it because its an SMTP server. As a solution I am using mailcatcher api directly to parse the messages and fetch the token.

Comment: @ashish could you please post your solution here as an answer? I think this might be useful to the topic visitors. Thanks!

Comment: Really sorry for being this late, I've posted my solution hope it helps you and the community. :)

Comment: @alecxe does this code still work for you?  Implementing an email validation test suite today and I'm considering both options (the mail-listener 2 and mailcatcher api)

Comment: @Gunderson yup, we've just switched to a different email provider and `mail-listener2` still works for us.

Comment: @alecxe awesome just tried it, incredibly easy to setup.  Pretty much just copied and pasted your code :) thanks

Comment: @alecxe Have you had any sporadic connection issues?  This works great 95% of the time, but every once in awhile I get an instant failure onPrepare from imap `Timed out while authenticating with server` -- I see some config options for `connTimeout` and `authTimeout` but it doesnt seem to wait for the time specified in those options

Comment: @Gunderson yeah, after switching to the new mail server we do have these kind of errors from time to time very rarely..do you have `tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` setting set?

Comment: Yep I have that set to false

Comment: @alecxe: nice solution... trying to use it for an E2E test for an Angular app, but I face the following error regarding the `email.subject`: `Property 'subject' does not exist on type '{}'` and the same for: `email.headers` `email.text`. Any idea pls.?

Comment: @alecxe: I fixed the issue regarding: `email.subject` and `email.text` by just changing it to: `email['subject']` and `email['text']`. But now facing the error: `- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` when trying to call/invoke the function: `getLastEmail()`. Any idea pls.?

Comment: @alecxe In my case I get a link for email that I need to click in this link to complete the registration of my user. Any ideia to manipulate this steps after access the email with mail-listener2? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting an error `(node:49611) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: deferred.fulfill is not a function`

Answer (score 7):

The solution I implemented was using mailcatcher [API](http://mailcatcher.me/), if you scroll down a bit you'll find the following about the API:

> A fairly RESTful URL schema means you can download a list of messages
>   in JSON from /messages, each message's metadata with
>   /messages/:id.json, and then the pertinent parts with
>   /messages/:id.html and /messages/:id.plain for the default HTML and
>   plain text version, /messages/:id/:cid for individual attachments by
>   CID, or the whole message with /messages/:id.source.

So we first fetched the whole json response, parse it and fetch the latest email id:

```
// Returns the last email id
function(emails, user) {
    var email, recipient;
    for(var i = emails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        email = emails[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < email.recipients.length ; j++) {
            recipient = email.recipients[j];
            if(recipient == "<"+user+">") {
                return email.id;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

using that email id we can get the body of the email by hitting `/messages/:id.plain`(of course there are more variants like fetching the email source code or email rendered html, we only needed the message) then we can just parse the body to fetch what we want, following is the code:

```
browser.driver.get(mailcatcherUrl+"/messages");
browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('body')).getText().then(function(response) {
    var emails, lastEmailId, partialTokens ;
    emails = JSON.parse(response);
    lastEmailId = getLastEmailId(emails, user);
    browser.driver.get(mailcatcherUrl+"/messages/"+lastEmailId+".plain");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('body')).getText().then(function(lastEmail) {
        // use latestEmail to get what you want.
    });
});
```

And Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the same thing but the mail testing server we were using did not have imap support.
So in case anyone runs into the same issue, I achieved a similar solution as alecxe using  [mailpop3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailpop3) npm library.

The thing with the pop3 client, however, was that it doesn't act as a listener so we had to define a helper function that would connect, login and fetch the latest email when we needed to test the latest email.

Something like this:

```
function getLastEmail() {
  var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
  var POP3Client = require("mailpop3");
  var client = new POP3Client(port, host, {
          tlserrs: false,
          enabletls: true,
          debug: false
      });

  client.on("connect", function() {
  
          console.log("CONNECT success");
          client.login(username, password);
  
  });

  client.on("login", function(status, rawdata) {
  
      if (status) {
  
          console.log("LOGIN/PASS success");
          client.retr(1);
  
      } else {
  
          console.log("LOGIN/PASS failed");
          client.quit();
  
      }
  });

  client.on("retr", function(status, msgnumber, data, rawdata) {
  
      if (status === true) {
  
          console.log("RETR success for msgnumber " + msgnumber);
          deferred.fulfill(data);
  
      } else {
  
          console.log("RETR failed for msgnumber " + msgnumber);
    
      }
      client.quit();
  });
  return deferred.promise;
}
```