# Unable to retrieve email information in protractor

Tags: javascript, email, protractor, e2e-testing

Referencing the information from the question [Fetching values from email in protractor test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311154/fetching-values-from-email-in-protractor-test-case), I am still unable to reference the emails.  In my test case, the 'expect' is not getting executed for some unknown reason to me.

Also if I use the line,

```
browser.controlFlow().await(getLastEmail()).then(...)
```

There is a 'browser.controlFlow(...).await is not a function error'

conf.js

```
var MailListener = require("mail-listener2")

exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
specs: ['./test.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: { defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000 },
allScriptsTimeout: 60000,

onPrepare: function () {

    var mailListener = new MailListener({
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        host: "imapPort",
        port: 993, // imap port
        secure: true,
        tls: true,
        tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
        mailbox: "INBOX", // mailbox to monitor
        searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", "FLAGGED"], // the search filter being used after an IDLE notification has been retrieved
        markSeen: true, // all fetched email willbe marked as seen and not fetched next time
        fetchUnreadOnStart: true, // use it only if you want to get all unread email on lib start. Default is `false`,
        mailParserOptions: {streamAttachments: true}, // options to be passed to mailParser lib.
        attachments: true, // download attachments as they are encountered to the project directory
        attachmentOptions: { directory: "attachments/" } // specify a download directory for attachments
    })

    mailListener.start()

    mailListener.on("server:connected", function(){
        console.log("Mail listener initialized")
    })

    mailListener.on("error", function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })

    mailListener.on("server:disconnected", function(){
      console.log("imapDisconnected")
    })

    global.mailListener = mailListener
},

onCleanUp: function () {
    mailListener.stop()
 }
}
```

The test case:

```
describe('Email Testing', function () {

 it('should login with a registration code sent to an email', function () {
   //this line causes a 'browser.controlFlow(...).await is not a function' error
  // browser.controlFlow().await(getLastEmail()).then(function (email) {
  getLastEmail().then(function (email) {
    // The expect does not get executed as it should fail
    expect(email.subject).toEqual('My Subject')
   })
 })
})

 function getLastEmail () {
   var deferred = protractor.promise.defer()
   console.log('Waiting for an email...')

   mailListener.on('mail', function (mail) {
     console.log('No Console Log Here!')
     deferred.fulfill(mail)
   })
  return deferred.promise
 }
```

I am not certain what I am missing in my test case to be able to read the subject or body of the email?

Comment: What protractor version are you using?

Comment: I am using protractor 3.1.1

Comment: Hello, I am seeing same error 'browser.controlFlow(...).await is not a function'  when using protractor @3.1.1. Would you please advise , if someone had already a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ran into the same issue today. Turns out the API for the webdriver and ControlFlow has been updated and *await* has been changed to *wait*. Yeah, subtle difference. See the new API reference here: https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise_exports_ControlFlow.html

To schedule a task for the wait condition, change your code to look like this:

```
browser.controlFlow().wait(getLastEmail()).then(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

you would basically have to wrap that asynchronous code inside of a promise and the pass that promise/function into the flow.execute()

```
var flow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
flow.execute( getLastEmail() ).then(function(email){
     text = email.text
});
```