# How to get the newest email with mail-listener2

Tags: email, protractor

I am using mail-listener2 to monitor an email account, as check that an email has been recieved as part of a test.

I have used the same implementation defined here:  here:[Fetching values from email in protractor test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311154/fetching-values-from-email-in-protractor-test-case/29382990#29382990)

However, getLastEmail() returns an old email, rather than an email received after the mail-listener2 has started.  It returns the first UNSEEN email.

I've looked at whether I can used different mail-listener2 configurations to solve this, but I haven't found anything.  I've also tried to use a .last() on the mail returned, but this hasn't worked either.

Does anyone have a configuration solution, or a custom solution that would help to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this may help you, I implemented mail-listener2 using the same post you followed and it works great me for me.  I just added a few extra parameters:

Under my config's `onPrepare`, I create a date:

`var emailDate = new Date().getTime();`

Then under my `mailListener` initialization:

```
    var mailListener = new MailListener({
        username: ...
        password: ...
        ...
        searchFilter: ["NEW", "UNSEEN", ["SINCE", emailDate]]
    });
```

This should configure mailListener to only look for emails delivered after the time of `emailDate`, which is created when your test is started.  You can also specify an exact date, i.e. `['SINCE', 'May 20, 2010']`

More info on the [node-imap](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap) docs (which mailListener2 utilizes)

Comment: Thank you! This works, and is just what I needed.  The link is also very useful.

Comment: I am using nightwatch for my e2e test. i am not sure how to use this mail-listener in nightwatch. because i do not have on prepare function in nightwatch. would you able to share the getLastEmail() ? so that i can have some ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration in conf file in the mailListener configurations:

```
markSeen: true,
```

Every-time you read the email, it is marked as read and will not be fetched next time. This means that you will always read new emails.

Answer (score 0):

In my case was not enough the previous answer due differences in the server time with gmail server time. So a complete way could be:

```
    var currentDate =  new Date().toUTCString()
    
    var mailListener = new MailListener({
        ...
        markSeen: true,
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
        searchFilter: ["UNSEEN", ["SINCE", currentDate]]
    });
```

then your getLastEmail helper could be:

```
getLastEmail = function () {
var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
console.log("Waiting for an email...");
const hrs = new Date().getUTCHours()
const minutes = new Date().getUTCMinutes()
mailListener.on("mail", function(mail){
    if( hrs=== new Date().getUTCHours("mail.headers.date") &&
        minutes- new Date().getUTCMinutes("mail.headers.date") <=1 ) {
        deferred.fulfill(mail);
    }
});

return deferred.promise;
}
```

This worked for me.