# How to do automation testing for text and email notification coming through a web app? (UI automation/API automation preferably in Javascript)

Tags: push-notification, automated-tests, email-notifications

I have tried writing code in Javascript(protractor) to open email and serach for notifications. Is there another way to test email notifications(API/UI automated test).

Also what tools/testing framework is suitable for text notification automated testing?

Comment: Note: I am trying to  test already received email/text notification

Comment: Email and text are different enough where I'd want to do them separately (hence separate questions).

Comment: @benc Can you suggest any solution to either Text or Email?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311154/fetching-values-from-email-in-protractor-test-case

Comment: Because email is often stored as files, the simplest approach is to locally deliver mail, then open it as a text file, and use whatever testing harness you prefer. For example, one time, I had mail sent to a macOS home directory, then used PERL.