# How to Read the Email Body in Gmail or Any other email provider for Login Url and Password in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to read the email body for Login Url and password in
Gmail or any other email provider.

Can anyone help?

Comment: hi check this question if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29311154/fetching-values-from-email-in-protractor-test-case

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan, Thanks for the input. I have tried the above solution and it gave a blank results. I used other alternative for email testing. Mailinator.com